# Huge issue with XAMPP's backup and restore feature

Tags: php, sql, apache, xampp, backup

So I've used the XAMPP backup and restore tool for backing up all of my websites and databases from my local XAMPP installation on my mac. Instructions for how to do this can be found on the [XAMPP website](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_osx.html) under the 'backup/restore my XAMPP system' section. The result of the backup was a 900MB shell script file.

Now I've just tried to restore the backup file generated by the script to a new installation of XAMPP using the command `sudo /Users/Joel/Desktop/xampp-backup-18-05-15.sh`, but I'm getting some strange errors:

```
Joels-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Joel$ sudo /Users/Joel/Desktop/xampp-backup-18-05-15.sh
Checking integrity of files...
egrep: md5sums: No such file or directory
md5: *: No such file or directory
Restoring configuration, log and htdocs files...
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'data.tar.gz'
Checking versions...
cat: VERSION: No such file or directory
Installed:   XAMPP 1.8.2-6
Backup from: XAMPP 
The backup sofware is not able to handle different XAMPP versions.
Your backuped configuration from  may not work with 1.8.2-6 and may need manually corrections.
XAMPP: Do you want to continue [nein] y
Let's try...
Restoring MySQL databases...
/Users/Joel/Desktop/xampp-backup-18-05-15.sh: line 184: *.sql: No such file or directory
* FAILED: cat: output: No such file or directory
Restoring MySQL user databases...
/Users/Joel/Desktop/xampp-backup-18-05-15.sh: line 193: mysql.sql: No such file or directory
MySQL user FAILED: cat: output: No such file or directory
Backup complete. Have fun!
You may need to restart XAMPP to complete the restore.
Joels-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Joel$
```

Why isn't the version of my previous XAMPP installation showing on line 12? I don't actually remember which version of XAMPP I had installed so this is my problem. Is there any other way of finding this out?

Also, has anyone else actually used this backup and restore script successfully before? I'll be absolutely gutted if I've lost all of my work because of this!!!

Comment: i suggest you ask here: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/

Comment: Okay thanks, just posted here: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=70798